# Error running the gem install update

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed Instant Rails 2.0. While trying to upgrade RubyGems I run the command `gem install update`. It fails giving following error.

> C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\InstantRails-2.0-win\rails_apps>gem install update
>   ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
>
> HTTP Response 302 fetching http://gems.rubyforge.org/yaml

Also it is giving same error while executing `gem update -- system`. or any other `gem` command.

Comment: Probably more importantly, you should choose a package that has a recent, stable, secure version of Rails. You'll notice that Instant Rails 2.0 came out in 2007 (almost exactly 5 years old as of this posting).

Comment: Chris, Thanks for your suggestion and time. Will try using more recent versions

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a more recent gem version from http://gems.rubyforge.org/